# Wordpress function only runs with user operator

Tags: wordpress, function, mailchimp

Help, I am very confused. I am using this function that sends user profile data to mailchimp and it works only if I have the `if user`.  Why does it do that and why does it work with any userid?

```
add_filter( 'mailchimp_sync_subscriber_data', function( $subscriber, $user ) {

  if ($user = 5) {   //if I remove this it doesn't work, and it can be any userid

    $sc =  get_user_meta( $user, 'supply_chain' );  

    if (in_array('yes', $sc)){
        $subscriber->interests[ 'b90fe65c1a' ] = true; 
    } else if (in_array('no', $sc)) {
        $subscriber->interests[ 'b90fe65c1a' ] = false;
    } 
}   

    return $subscriber;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: You have a typo in there: `if ($user = 5)` should be `if ($user == 5)` instead. As a reminder: `=` -> assignation, `==` -> comparison.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  But I still don't know why it works when it has that typo? Just a reminder that the function works as it is (even with typo) but does NOT work when I remove that condition.

Comment: Because when PHP evaluates that this is what happens: `$user = 5` equals `5`. `5` is not equal to `0` (which is evaluated as `false`), therefore `5` is considered as `true` and so the validation passes.

Comment: If the condition was `$user == 5`, then PHP evaluates the value of `$user` against `5`: if `$user` is equal to `5` then the validation passes and the code inside the `if` condition is executed. If `$user` is something else (eg. `10`) then the validation will fail (`10` is not equal to `5`) and so the code won't be executed.

Comment: Ah yes, I see.  Thanks again for your time and explanation.